# How do I find the data rate per sec going through my router?

Tags: linux-networking, router

I have a Linux based router. I can figure out the number of TCP established connection using ss -s.

However, I am wondering how much data are passing by in all those connections. How do I figure this out ?

The reason I want to figure this out is it seems to me that although the number of connections seems less (I got 15 users behind the router), it seems there is heavy usage. Is there a way I could figure out how much data per sec is passing through all these connections ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various command line tools to monitor your interfaces in live mode. There are e.g. `dstat`, `iftop`, `nethogs`.

If you want to save the results over time and create graphs, you should have a look at [Ganglia](http://ganglia.sourceforge.net/), [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/), [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).